# Does $.addClass not update the DOM immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Consider the following snippet.

```
function foo(event) {
  var $item = $(event.target);
  $item.addClass("className");
  bar(event);
};

function bar(event) {
  var $item = $(event.target);

  // The following return false
  if ($item.hasClass("className")) {
    // flow of control does not enter
  }

};
```

I am not asking how to get around this. That would be plain obvious: to pass the reference to the `$item` to the `bar` function.

I am asking if jQuery:

1. Does or does not update the DOM immediately?
2. When does it update?
3. How can I make it update explicitly?
4. Finally, where can I read about this?

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure if I understand, you say that it doesn't update the DOM immediately and the condition is evaluated as false?

Comment: Seems to apply straight away to me: http://jsfiddle.net/szk96dt4/ - click the test div, it turns red and the console logs the stuff in the if

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code shown. Can you please explain what className changes to the element so e know if it causes reflow or repaint? That's also more or less the answer to the questions. Depending on what the class changes, it'll be in the DOM after the next reflow or repaint.

Comment: @Pete: It doesn't turn red in your jsfiddle and the console also doesn't log the message for me.

Comment: What browser are you using I tested in chrome and firefox - both turn red and log the message

Comment: @Pete I am using Firefox 62.0.6, which is probably the latest update.

Comment: hmm I'm using 62.0.2 (64bit) - on windows which says it is the latest version!  Think you may have a dodgy version if yours is 62.0.6: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am constantly switching between my code window and this one so I mistyped it. It's the same as yours.

Comment: I have tested the fiddle in chrome ( works ), firefox 62.0.2 ( works ) and IE11 ( does not work due to a jsfiddle error ) . I cannot reproduce the problem on my local machine either. And I cannot reproduce the problem when I rewrite all the JQuery into vanilla javascript. So the most likely issue become something with your local enviroment or in code not shown. I'll assume the code shown is complete. Are you using a very old version of JQuery for example? Or some other library that might conflict with JQuery?

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed - if so try disabling them all - I have found they sometimes interfere with js

Answer (score 1):

1. Does or does not update the DOM immediately?

Yes. Immediately.

2. When does it update?

The property/attribute of the DOM is updated immediately, you can read the changed value immediately. But the UI rendering may delay to the end of the JavaScript code (UI rendering doesn't matter).

3. How can I make it update explicitly?

You don't need to.

4. Finally, where can I read about this?

Well ... I think the DOM/ES standards may contain these contents.

And you can think about the "correct behavior" of a design: who can bear the strange behavior that can not read the changed value immediately? It must be crazy. So your browser always do the right things.  :D

5. See your demo here, works without any problem (if it doesn't work, it is your browser's problem, maybe buggy version, or caused by some buggy plugins)

```js
function foo(event) {
  var $item = $(event.target);
  $item.addClass("className");
  bar(event);
};

function bar(event) {
  var $item = $(event.target);
  if ($item.hasClass("className")) {
    $("#output").text("className changed!")
  }

};

$(function(){
  $("#test").on("click", foo);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test">click me</button>
<div id="output">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should perform as expected, there's no apparent problem with it, but here's the thing that might be creating problems

when you do addClass, it triggers an even that updates the class='' attribute and removes your className, which is why the condition

```
($item.hasClass("className"))
```

returns false